# Trocar posições do sidebar diretamente no phpmyadmin

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou tendo um problema no wordpress onde ele não está deixando `clicar` e `arrastar`para trocar as posições dos widgets (não só os widgets mas o site todo). Eu preciso trocar somente as posições de 2 widgets que estão lá, gostaria de colocar os 2 últimos em primeiro, mas não consegui até o momento. Fui até a tabela **options** e editei o **sidebars_widgets** mas não me deu nenhum resultado, parece que não aconteceu nada.

Esse é o conteúdo do **sidebars_widgets** que tenho:

```
a:7:{
    s:19:"wp_inactive_widgets";
    a:0:{}
    s:9:
    "sidebar-1";
    a:3:{
        i:0;s:18:"bp_groups_widget-3";
        i:1;s:19:"bp_group_calendar-3";
        i:2;s:22:"widget_tdlcbirthdays-3";
    }
    s:24:"first-footer-widget-area";
    a:0:{}
    s:25:"second-footer-widget-area";
    a:0:{}
    s:24:"third-footer-widget-area";
    a:0:{}s:25:"fourth-footer-widget-area";
    a:0:{}s:13:"array_version";i:3;
}
```

Comment: Se não está funcionando é porque tem algum plugin ou tema que está conflitando. Já tentou desativar os plugins? Se tiver muitos plugins comece por aqueles que vc acha que são mais Insignificante, desative de 3 em três. Quando a ordenação dos widgets voltar a funcionar, você ordena e ativa os plugins novamente. Vale testar com outro navegador também. Outra dica é olhar no console do navegador e verificar se está dando erro.

Comment: O código que você colocou acima é original ou já é o modificado? Se for o modificado posta o código original se ainda tiver mas posta em texto corrido da forma que está no banco

Comment: @FabianoCacinPinel É o origional esse. Só coloquei dessa forma pra entender melhor, mas está tudo em 1 linha só

Comment: eu tentei e converter em array usando a função maybe_unserialize do wordpress da forma que você passou e não mostrou nada. Fiz um teste usando um código do meu wordpress e funcionou.

Comment: Se no seu tema ou em algum plugin estiverem configurando a posição dos widgets vc não vai nunca conseguir fazer isso alterando direto no banco de dados. Pq vc pode mudar lá mas ai o código roda e muda novamente. Meu palpite é algo no seu tema. Olha no arquivo functions.php ou da um "extenteded search" por widgets nos arquivos do seu tema.